# How is an SMTP-Client supposed to behave if he receives an Error from the Server?

Tags: postfix, smtp, milter, opensmtpd, rspamd

Consider the following SMTP-Session:

```
220 mx.example.com ESMTP Postfix
EHLO example.com
250-mx.example.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250 SMTPUTF8
MAIL FROM:<>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:<test@example.com>
250 2.1.5 Ok
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Subject: Test
Test
.
451 4.7.1 Try again later
```

What is a client supposed to do after this? Is he allowed to send an `RSET` and try another Mail?

This Question is loosely related to [this rspamd issue](https://github.com/vstakhov/rspamd/issues/1764) and I am not sure who behaves wrong:

- rspamd for not handling multiple mails in one session correctly if the first delivery fails
- Postfix for not sending rspamd the correct Milter Commands
- OpenSMTPd for delivering another mail after one that already failed

Comment: In general the RFC mandated and implied behaviour is to attempt delivery of each message and in case of an transient error to retry the failed message(s) after *a while* and be intelligent about retrying. See 
RFC 5321
[section-4.2.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-4.2.1) and [section-4.5.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-4.5.4)

Comment: Making @HBruijn reply more specific: You may try to send another message(s) over this SMTP session. IMHO it may make sense to drop SMTP session after two such temporary rejects [my personal rule of thumb]

Comment: Thanks, thats already helpful. So it seems that OpenSMTPd and Postfix are probably behaving correctly (according to the RFC, which is not very specific on the "in this session"-part) and rspamd has some kind of bug which always rejects the second (third, fourth...) message after the first has not succeeded.